# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar script de Django dentro de un enviroment desde cron?

Tags: python, django, bash, cron

Estoy tratando de automatizar unos script que deben ser corridos dependiendo del enviroment de Django.

Esto funciona correctamente pero no lo he podido automatizar.

```
workon dominio.com
/var/virtualenv/dominio.com/bin/python manage.py shell

Python 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:08:31) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: run cron.py
```

He intentado:

```
/var/virtualenv/dominio.com/bin/python manage.py shell < cron.py
```

Si bien lo corre pareciera que no lo corre dentro del script, porque no ejecuta los cambios necesarios.

También he probado de poner el path absoluto de cada uno:

```
/var/virtualenv/dominio.com/bin/python /var/www/dominio.com/web/shop4/shop/manage.py shell < /var/www/dominio.com/web/shop4/shop/cron.py
```

Comment: Hola, ¿por qué quieres hacerlo a traveś del shell y no lo usas ejecutando en Python directamente con `python cron.py`? El shell es una herramienta de Django pero no es necesaria para ejecutar scripts si ya estás dentro del ambiente virtual usando el `workon`.

Comment: @César entonces `workon` es el equivalente a `source env/bin/activate`?

Comment: @César , pues por que no puedo ejecutar workon desde un bas script para automatizar la tarea, o al menos alli intenta apuntar la consulta.

Comment: @fedorqui exactamente el workon es parte de un conjuntos de scripts de virtual envwrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lanzar scripsts de django en cron uso lo siguiente:

http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runscript.html

esto te hará  instalar un paquete: 'django_extensions' , crear una carpeta /scripts en el directorio de tu proyecto i eso te dejará llamar scripts de Django via bash:

```
python manage.py runscript <<script_name>> --script-args <<args>>
```

como se pueden llamar via bash, los puedes añadir a tu cron fácilmente:

```
crontab -e
```

Añadir los scripts:

```
#cada 15 minutos un script llamado envio_alertas
*/15 * * * *    cd /pathatu/proyecto; python manage.py runscript envio_alertas 
#todos los dias a las 22h, un script llamado validar_reparaciones
* * 22 * *      cd /pathatu/proyecto; python manage.py runscript validar_reparaciones
```